# How to change spinner background color?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have prepared custom spinner with text color and text size using adapter.By default spinner background color while ,here i want to change white to some other color or image?

Is there any change to change backgroung color of spinner?. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
         ...
         android:background="#YOUR_HEXA_COLOR"/>
```

This didn't work for you?

Else if you are using a custom Spinner you can have it from this [`Blog`](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57).

Comment: this is work for any of spinner button.When click the "Spinner Button" one screen will be display.i want to change that screen backgroung.

Answer (score 0):

I made my custom spinner by totally write a new view.(A LinearLayout contains several item)
When click the "Spinner Button" I add the custom view to the screen, just pretend to be a spinner, then I can do a lot of custom things on it. :)